# Im getting the same one error over and over

Tags: java

this is my error. Does anyone know the problem to why im getting this error ? Im using JGrasp

```
PeerTutorReport.java:13: error: <identifier> expected
    public static String[] getTutorNames(listNames) {
                                                  ^
1 error
```

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Report {

public static void main(String[] args) {


      String[] listNames = getTutorNames();
}

public static String[] getTutorNames(listNames) {

      String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String[] listNames = new String[10];

    for (int x = 0; x < listNames.length; x++) {
        firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's First Name: ");
        lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's Last Name: ");

        if (firstName.equals("") && lastName.equals("")) {
            break; // loop end
        }
        listNames[x] = lastName + ", " + firstName;
    }
    return listNames;
}
```

}

Comment: **Please** do not edit the initial question, otherwise answers will be invalid. Instead, add new content on the question with updated to your code.

Comment: I downvoted this question for poor research effort.  It's a syntax issue, the error message (though vague, as per typical java syntax error messages) highlights part of the issue.

Comment: **Please read the comments**

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be passing an argument to this method.

```
 getTutorNames(someArg); //This is how you'd call the `getTutorNames(String[] listNames)` method.
```

Also this should be like this:-

```
public static String[] getTutorNames(String[] listNames){ // Give a type for the "listNames" argument
```

Also, you need to have a different name for either the argument here `getTutorNames(String[] listNames)` or have a different name for `String[] listNames = new String[10];` in the `getTutorNames` method.

**Update:-** The below code does work. Checked personally.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] listNames = getTutorNames();
}

public static String[] getTutorNames() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: in that case, just change the `getTutorNames` method signature to this `public static String[] getTutorNames()`.

Comment: @AngieMckenzie- See the update in my code. Do that, and if it still doesn't work, post the exact error message here.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors:

1. You have to define a type for `listNames` argument.

   ```
   public static String[] getTutorNames(listNames) { //type of listNames??
   ```
2. Your `getTutorNames` needs you to pass an argument:

   ```
   String[] listNames = getTutorNames(); //argument here!
   ```

Looks like you need to remove the `listNames` argument for your `getTutorNames` method.

```
public static String[] getTutorNames() {
    //code content...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature should be, Note the `String` in the parameter that was missing in your method.

```
public static String[] getTutorNames(String listNames)
```

And you need to pass the String while invoking the method. Like

```
String[] listNames = getTutorNames("someName");
```

***Or***

Change your method as below that takes no parameters

```
public static String[] getTutorNames()
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the signaure of getTutorNames() to not accept any argument. That's what you want. Its wrongly defined anyway.